# How to read data from CSV into nested key-value pairs for future retrieval?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, csv, dictionary

I have a CSV file (`data.csv`) that looks like:

```
Time,Data1,Data2,Data3
0,10,25,100
1,20,30,120
2,25,35,125
3,30,50,150
```

I want to be able to access the data for a given column at a specified time (for example: inputs of `Data1` and `Time: 1` should return `20`).

I tried:

```
import csv

dataFile = 'data.csv'

with open(dataFile) as inputData:
    csv_input = csv.reader(inputData)
    headers = next(csv_input)
    data = list(zip(*[map(int, row) for row in csv_input]))

my_list = list(zip(data[0], data[1:]))
my_dictionary = dict(zip(headers, my_list))

print(my_dictionary['Data1'][1])
```

However, this returns:

```
(25, 30, 35, 50)
```

I would instead like to return:

```
20
```

How can I update my code to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping part posters original software

```
import csv

dataFile = 'data.csv'

with open(dataFile) as inputData:
    csv_input = csv.reader(inputData)
    headers = next(csv_input)
    data = list(zip(*[map(int, row) for row in csv_input]))
```

Modification, dicitonary is simply:

```
my_dictionary = dict(zip(headers, data))

print(my_dictionary ['Data1'][1])
>>> 20
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to load the immense Panda library to read a CSV file.Python provides modules for this:

```py
import csv
import collections

filename = "data_80.csv"


def read_csv(filename):
    columns = collections.defaultdict(list)
    with open(filename, 'rt') as file:
        rows = csv.DictReader(file)
        for row in rows:
            for key, val in row.items():
                columns[key].append(val)
    return dict(columns)  

data = read_csv(filename)

print(data) # data is a dictionary of list
{
'Time': ['0', '1', '2', '3'], 
'Data1': ['10', '20', '25', '30'], 
'Data2': ['25', '30', '35', '50'], 
'Data3': ['100', '120', '125', '150']
}

# You just can do 
print(data['Data1'][0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html).

Like this,

```
import pandas as pd
```

I made a file from your provided data and imported,

```
df = pd.read_csv('rcsv.csv')

print(df.head())
```

It looks like this,

```
Time  Data1  Data2  Data3
0     0     10     25    100
1     1     20     30    120
2     2     25     35    125
3     3     30     50    150
```

You get a specific element like this (second element in second column, zero indexed)

```
print(df.iloc[1][1])

20
```

If you have a [date and/or time](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) axis then we could approach it differently.

Answer (score 0):

Solution without `pandas`:

```
import csv

dataFile = 'data.csv'

with open(dataFile) as inputData:
    csv_input = csv.reader(inputData)
    i = zip(next(csv_input), zip(*csv_input))
    data, (_, times) = {}, next(i)
    for k, line in i:
        for t, l in zip(times, line):
            data.setdefault(k, {}).setdefault(t, {})
            data[k][int(t)] = l

print(data['Data1'][1])
```

Prints:

```
20
```